# Property in custom Angular directive link function always null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

[Plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mT78IMQyNbTv4fDffhsn?p=info)

I have a custom directive I'm build to display basic user data. The HTML template is able to render the user data using {{xxx}} syntax, but I also need to use one of the properties from the user data object to retrieve a photo of the user.

My problem is that within the link function the personData value is always null. I added a $observe on person, but it is always null also.

Is there a way observe changes to the personData object and perform action on change?

Directive Code:

```
app.directive('graphPerson', ['$http', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      personData: '=person'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log("Directive was linked");
      console.log($scope.personData);
      attrs.$observe('person', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log($scope.personData);
        if ($scope.personData) {
          //hard-coded photo for demo purposes
          $scope.myPhoto = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Blank_woman_placeholder.svg/315px-Blank_woman_placeholder.svg.png";
        }
      });
    },
    templateUrl: 'graph-person.html',

  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your intent is to monitor changes made to the `personData` object and not to the actual value of the DOM attribute `person` in your directive.  Is that correct?

I would use `$scope.$watch()` here.

See:  http://plnkr.co/edit/SU5x1F5tZKQWk4VK5OGO

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.personData = null;
  $scope.people = [
   {
      "displayName": "Katie Jordan",
      "givenName": "Katie",
      "jobTitle": "Auditor",
      "mail": "KatieJ@demo.com",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": "12/1110",
      "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
      "surname": "Jordan",
      "userPrincipalName": "KatieJ@demo.com",
      "id": "a0da13e4-1866-492e-96e6-8a2a4b60f650"
   },
   {
      "displayName": "James Jordan",
      "givenName": "James",
      "jobTitle": "Auditor",
      "mail": "JamesJ@demo.com",
      "mobilePhone": null,
      "officeLocation": "12/1110",
      "preferredLanguage": "en-US",
      "surname": "Jordan",
      "userPrincipalName": "JamesJ@demo.com",
      "id": "b0da13e4-1866-492e-96e6-8a2a4b60f651"
   }
  ];
  $scope.clickMe = function(index) {
    $scope.personData = $scope.people[index];
  }

});
app.directive('graphPerson', ['$http', function() {
  function getImageUrl(id)
  {
    console.log("I should get the URL For: " + id);
    return id;
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      personData: '=person'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log("Directive was linked");

      $scope.$watch('personData', function(newValue) {
        console.log($scope.personData);
        if ($scope.personData) {
          $scope.myPhoto = getImageUrl($scope.personData.id);
        }
      });
    },
    templateUrl: 'graph-person.html',

  };

}]);
```